# NoClassDefFoundError java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.VideoCastManager

Tags: google-cast

i trying to build a cast application in android using cast companion library. but when i run android project it gives above exception. i also included cast companion library.

How to remove this Exception.

Comment: Hi, Did you solve this issue? I have the same issue when I run with ProGuard.

Answer (score 0):

That means you have not setup your projects correctly and your android project cannot find the CCL on its path